# yii 1.x after extending component with thread yii models not working

Tags: php, multithreading, yii, pthreads

I have add pthreads in my xampp and its working fine without yii framework and also in yii framework by yii models, yii functions and included extension e.g. yiimailer is not working in this class, echo Yii::app()->basePath; is also not working

## My component class

```
class SendEmailThreads extends Thread{
    private $sendTo;
    private $subject;
    private $bodyText;
    public function __construct($sendTo, $subject, $bodyText){
        $this->sendTo = $sendTo;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->bodyText = $bodyText;
    }
    function run(){
        echo Yii::app()->basePath;
        sleep(1);


    }
}
```

## Used Here

```
public function actionBulkEmail(){    

for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){

   $pool[] = new SendEmailThreads('frazghuman@gmail.com','test bulk','test by fraz'); 
 }

 foreach($pool as $worker){
    $worker->start();
 }

 foreach($pool as $worker){
    $worker->join();
 }
```

}

Comment: I have add pthreads in my xampp and its working fine without yii framework and also in yii framework but yii models, yii functions and included extension e.g. yiimailer is not working in this class, echo Yii::app()->basePath; is also not working

Comment: I was call the action via browser
error is
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cbtTeamProject\protected\components\SendEmailThreads.php on line 20 - 3 times
due to echo Yii::app()->basePath;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that pthreads does not copy static members that are objects (with the exception of `Threaded` and `Closure` objects). This means that inside of the new thread, `null` is being returned when attempting to fetch the single instance via `Yii::app()`.

The only workaround that I can think of for this - which, I have no idea of its suitability, given that I've never used Yii before - is to create a new singleton instance *per thread*.

Really, though, global state should be considered a red flag when it comes to threading. Therefore, if an application or framework makes heavy use of it (as do most PHP frameworks nowadays, it would seem), then threading isn't really a viable option.